# Avoid duplicate files on migrate update

Tags: migrations

I am creating file entities with migrate using drush. Image files are being copied down from a remote server.
I tried

```
$this->addFieldMapping('file_replace')->defaultValue('FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE');
$this->addFieldMapping('preserve_files')->defaultValue(TRUE);
```

If I run the migration with --update it duplicates the files, not replacing existing ones.

```
drush mi DAProductImages --limit="10 items" --update
```

When I run this first time it creates the files. Second time it adds _0 to the filenames and duplicates the files. If I rollback after first migration the files are being removed. When rolling back after the second migration only files of last batch get removed. I also tried with:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('preserve_files')->defaultValue(FALSE);
```

How can I make it so that I will not end up with duplicates? I have about 30000 images so I cannot afford that.

Comment: Have you tried `FILE_EXISTS_REUSE`?

Comment: Yes, I am still getting the duplicated file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved it for me.

The documentation at [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1540106) was missing a mention that you need to use the class prefix - I just submitted an update to the Drupal Docs to make it more clear:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('preserve_files')
  ->defaultValue(1);

$this->addFieldMapping('file_replace')
  ->defaultValue(MigrateFile::FILE_EXISTS_REUSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_document', 'field_document_uri');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_document:file_replace')->defaultValue(MigrateFile::FILE_EXISTS_REUSE);
```

Found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1540106).